# How to transform List<Single<String>> to List<String>?

Tags: rx-java

I have a list `List<Single<String>>` which I want to turn into a `List<String>` .

The order should be preserved and all Single's should be processed in parallel.

```
List<Single<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  list.add(createSingle(i));
}

// Dummy method which creates a single instance
private Single<String> createSingle(int i) {
  return Single.create(sub -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(800);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      sub.onSuccess("test_" + i);
    }).start();
  });
}
```

My initial implementation used `Observable.concatWith` but that will basically prevent parallel processing because each single is subscribed one after the other.

I also know that I can turn the list of Singles into one Observable which emits the strings but I loose the order in that case.

```
List<Observable<String>> obsList = list.stream().map(Single::toObservable).collect(Collectors.toList());
Observable.merge(obsList).....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
List<Single<String>> list = ...

Observable.from(list)
.concatMapEager(s -> s.toObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
.toList()
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: That is not preserving the order at all. 
```[test_0, test_3, test_6, test_2, test_8, test_9, test_1, test_4, test_5, test_7]```

Comment: Very nice... works perfectly. The subscribeOn can be omitted in my case.